# Horizontal scroll of three buttons mouse in Kubuntu

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, mouse, kde, mouse-scroll

I have Kubuntu 18.04 and three buttons mouse, left, right and clickable scroll wheel. It is Genius NetScroll+. Indeed it is very old, I purchased it since the year 2002. However, I could not able to initiate horizontal scroll by clicking the scroll wheel and drag horizontally.

I have tried:

> **System Settings ⇒ Input Devices ⇒ Mouse**

However, there is no any thing about scrolling in that configuration section.

[image]

Is there any solution for this issue?